# How to check if device has TikTok installed in device?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to check if a device has TikTok installed.
Currently I am trying with:

```
func canOpenTiktok() -> Bool {
    if let url = URL(string: "tiktok://app") {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

but that always returns false, regardless of whether or not Tiktok is installed.

Is there a way to check?

Comment: are u tried with `tiktok://` this

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes. Still returns false..

Comment: Did you include the URL in the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your `info,plist`?

Comment: @Paulw11 exactly! What a miss... Just found out, and wanted to update with solution! Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `info.plist` adding `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` and under `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` add TikTok